# Android - How to download the file from google drive to android SDCARD?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have uploaded an apk file in google drive using the desktop.

Now I need to download that apk file to in to my android SDCARD when I click on a button in my android activity. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to use the [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), since you have to open Drive in a DRIVE_FILE scope. The [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) has only FILE scope and will not see anything your Android app did not create.

In the RESTful API, it is a 3 step process

1. use [LIST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to get the file URL (query by 'title')
2. use [GET](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) (actually getContent()) to retrieve the file content
3. get binary stream and save it to your SD card

In both step 1 and 2, use the 'try it' playground at the bottom of the pages to form your query and field selection correctly. Step 3 is well documented elsewhere. Here's some out-of-context code that may help

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions
  .android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential _crd  = 
  GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive _svc =
new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), _crd).build();

// step 1: get the file list of files
com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList gooLst = 
 _svc.files().list().setQ( [YOUR_REQUEST_STRING])
    .setFields("items(title,downloadUrl)").execute();
// get the URL from your list matching the title with the requested one

// step 2: get the file contents 
InputStream is = _svc.getRequestFactory()
 .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl([URL_FROM_LIST]))
 .execute().getContent();

// step 3: stream it to you file
strm2File(is, [YOUR_FILE_NAME]);

private void strm2File(InputStream inStrm, String flNm) {
  try {
    OutputStream outStrm = 
        new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(_ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null), flNm));
    try {
      try {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read; 
        while (((read = inStrm.read(buffer)) != -1) && (!isCancelled()))
          outStrm.write(buffer, 0, read);
        outStrm.flush();
      } finally {outStrm.close();}
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    inStrm.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Steps 1 and 2 in the code above have to be in the non-UI thread (like AsyncTask) and there is a lot of error handling that has to be implemented (*UserRecoverableAuthIOException*...) around it.

Comment: can you explain more about YOUR_REQUEST_STRING and URL_FROM_LIST?

Comment: YOUR_REQUEST_STRING - see variable "qryClause" here : https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java.  URL_FROM_LIST - gooLst is a list of objects, each has a "downloadUrl" member var.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to accomplish using the new Android API.  If the app that uploaded it on the web has the same app id as the one on Android, your app will already have access to the file.  In that case you can use the [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#query%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Query%29) functionality to locate the file.

Otherwise, you can use the [OpenFileActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html) and ask the user to select the apk they want to download.

Once you have the DriveId of the file, you can open the contents following the [read contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#reading_files) guide.

Comment: You got me confused here. Are you saying, that if a user for instance uploads the file using his browser (draganddrop), the Android app has access to it?

Comment: No, if there is a web app that uploaded the file, the matching Android app will have access. If the file was uploaded using the Drive Web UI, then you need to use the OpenFileActivity flow.

Comment: Sorry (obnoxious is my middle name), does it mean that OpenFileActivity flow works under DRIVE_FILE scope?

Comment: Yes, one of the primary purposes of the OpenFileActivity is to allow users to grant your app access to specific files.  It will always show all files in the users drive, and your app will be granted access to the specific selected file.  This allows you to work with user's files without requiring a scary level of access to their entire Drive.

Comment: @seanpj Can you see my post?[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407368/android-drive-api-download-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407368/android-drive-api-download-file

Comment: I have retired a few moths ago, sorry.