# How to download file from Google Drive and restore db from it

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Using the quickstart provided by Google I managed to upload a copy of my SQLite DB to my Google Drive properly. My only problem now is getting it back and restoring using that file.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627428/android-how-to-download-the-file-from-google-drive-to-android-sdcard) that since I've already uploaded the file I should have access to it as well. So far I can follow that, but when it goes down to reading the contents I get confused.

I'm still new so I can barely understand the processes I see on the demos, so far from what I can tell all I can do right now is ( I hope I'm actually doing it, I just follow the demos ) locate it. So now I'm stuck at HOW do I get it back? Can anyone lend a hand?

My original plan was to just download the file into a specified folder on my SD and just restore from that since I already know how to do backups and restoration from SD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull down the GDAA CRUD wrapper [from here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GDAA.java). It uses the simplest form of GDAA calls, the 'await' flavor. As long as you wrap any of these calls to non-UI threads (Thread, AsyncTask) you should be OK.
If you decide to go this way (see how GDAA class communicates with MainActivity - connection, authorization), you basically need 3 methods:

1. [search](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GDAA.java#L106) for your file using it's title, mime, or whatever criteria you have, resulting in a valid DriveId. You may also use the DriveId you obtained from previous [upload](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GDAA.java#L143).
2. [read](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GDAA.java#L195) the file content into a byte[] buffer
3. [save](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/UT.java#L97) your buffer into a DB file on your android device.

The [demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) shows uploading / downloading of JPEG images to/from the Drive (disregard the REST branch, it is there only for testing). You're dealing with a DB file, but in the end it still is a buffer/stream full of binary data that is uploaded/downloaded (with some metadata like title, mimetype,...).

Good Luck