# Download a file and save to sd card using google drive api in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to download a file from google drive using google drive api and after downloading the file i want to save the file into my sd card.

I have got the resource id which i want to download like that .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "in onActivityResult() - triggered on pressing Select");
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SELECT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                /*get the selected item's ID*/
                DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                        OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);//this extra contains the drive id of the selected file
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected folder's ID: " + driveId.encodeToString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected folder's Resource ID: " + driveId.getResourceId());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),driveId.encodeToString()+":"+driveId.getResourceId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            finish();
            break;

        case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "in onActivityResult() - resolving connection, connecting...");
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;


        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Now i dont know how to download the file using this resource id of the file and then save to the sd card.
I have search a lot into google but can't get a proper solution.
Is there anyone who can help me to solve this??

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627428/android-how-to-download-the-file-from-google-drive-to-android-sdcard?