# download errors, can't open files

Tags: android, download, google-drive-android-api

My app has to connect to google drive. The connection works fine.
I can see all the files in the drive. The download of the files works fine.
Unfortunately when I try to open it the files are corrupted or I can't open them at all. Does anyone know a solution for this problem ??

`enter code here`

```
URL url = new URL(fileURL);

HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

// always check HTTP response code first
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    String fileName = "";
    String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
    String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
    int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

    if (disposition != null) {
        // extracts file name from header field
        int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
        if (index > 0) {
            fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                    disposition.length() - 1);
        }
    } else {
        // extracts file name from URL
        fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                fileURL.length());
    }
    System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
    System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
    System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
    fileName = mr.getTitle();
    // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
    // URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

     InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
     FileOutputStream outputStream = new
     FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
    // opens an output stream to save into file



    int bytesRead = 0;
    // int read;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
    // while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    // outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    // }
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

     outputStream.flush();  
     outputStream.close();
     inputStream.close();

    System.out.println("File downloaded");
} else {
    System.out
            .println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: "
                    + responseCode);
}
httpConn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Did you compare file sizes?

Comment: how did you intialize `saveDir`?

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner you mean ?? 

public static void downloadFile(Metadata mr, String fileURL, String saveDir)
throws IOException {

Answer (score 0):

It's problem between your file length and byte buffer. For quickly, please change to and retry

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

or you could get the length of input stream then create buffer

```
long streamLength = inputStream.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[streamLength];
```

Have fun!

Comment: no...doesn't work...when i try to open the file i can't, file not valid format.By the way thank you

Comment: OK guys I know the real problem, if you want to use an app that connect to your google drive profile and download files you have to set the file public on drive before.
Otherwise when you download you can't open the stored file because there is a security block from google and in log cat you have 
"android content-disposition null"
"android content-lenght -1"
"android content-Type text/plain"
for every kind of file....

someone know how to solve it???

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627428/android-how-to-download-the-file-from-google-drive-to-android-sdcard, note that you should choose your Google acc which have permission to download file before, by using setSelectedAccountName(String accountName)