# Android Drive api Download file

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm successfully using [this project](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) to create or modify a file in Google Drive. Now I need to download the file to the external memory of device. I can read the contents of the file, and I can save it. But when I try to open it in the desktop, the file is corrupted.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mBusy = true;
         ArrayList<ContentValues> cvs = GDAA.searchDB(UT.FILE_NAME);
                if (cvs != null) for (ContentValues cv : cvs) {
                    String gdid = cv.getAsString(UT.GDID);
                    System.out.println("ID..... " + gdid);
                     byte[] buf = GDAA.read(gdid);
                     String str = buf == null ? "" : new String(buf);
                     File fl = UT.str2File(str, "myfile.db");


                        }
    ----------------------------------------------
    static File str2File(String str, String name) {
    if (str == null) return null;
    byte[] buf = str.getBytes();

    File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name);

    if (fl == null) return null;
    BufferedOutputStream bs = null;
    try {
      bs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fl));
      bs.write(buf);
    } catch (Exception e) { le(e); }
    finally {
      if (bs != null) try {
        bs.close();
      } catch (Exception e) { le(e); }
    }
    return fl;
  }

    ----------------------------------------------
    static byte[] read(String id) {
        byte[] buf = null;
        if (mGAC != null && mGAC.isConnected() && id != null) try {
            DriveFile df = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGAC, DriveId.decodeFromString(id));
            DriveContentsResult rslt = df.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
            if ((rslt != null) && rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                DriveContents cont = rslt.getDriveContents();
                buf = UT.is2Bytes(cont.getInputStream());
                cont.discard(mGAC);    // or cont.commit();  they are equiv if READONLY
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UT.le(e);
        }
        return buf;
    }
```

Comment: You have to create a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code to download from google drive

you just need to pass driveId and file name that you want to save on sd card

```
 private void DownloadFile(final DriveId driveId, final File filename) {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                if (!filename.exists()) {
                    try {
                        filename.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(
                        GapiClient, driveId);
                file.getMetadata(GapiClient)
                        .setResultCallback(metadataRetrievedCallback);
                DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                        GapiClient,
                        DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
                DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult
                        .getDriveContents();
                InputStream inputstream = driveContents.getInputStream();

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(filename);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    while ((bufferLength = inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                    fileOutput.close();
                    inputstream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }

        };
        task.execute();
    }

    private ResultCallback<MetadataResult> metadataRetrievedCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }
            metadata = result.getMetadata();
        }
    };
```

Comment: How to get filename based on driveId  ? any idea ?

Comment: i think you get file from this line >> DriveFile file = Drive.DriveAPi.getFile(GapiClient, driveId); Please explore file and i hope you will get the file name.

Comment: Drive.DriveApi is deprecated.

Comment: @LubošStaráček I have done it in 2016.. If you have found a new a way then Please please update the answer... If i got time to look in to i will definitely update the answer.
Thanks

Comment: I see. However, that's quite poorly documented area of Android, but I'll update the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //connecting to url
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            if (!rootDir.exists()) {
                rootDir.mkdirs();
            }

            //lenghtOfFile is used for calculating download progress
            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

            //this is where the file will be seen after the download
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(rootDir, fileName));
            //file input is from the url
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();


            //here’s the download code
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            long total = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                total += len1; //total = total + len1
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

save file with its extension . same happened to me

eg if your file name is xyz and you save it without extension sometimes things go wrong if you save file with extension say xyz.pdf you should not face this problem